# chmod in java according to mode and not Strings

Tags: java

I have a dynamic int in java which represents the mode e.g.s : 450, 777 etc
I need to change the existing file permissions, I tried exploring Files.setPosixFilePermissions Api but this requires mode in String format like -rw-r--r--

```
Files.setPosixFilePermissions(
    path,
    PosixFilePermissions.fromString("-rw-r--r--")
);
```

But what if its numbers instead of Strings like 450, 777 which can be anything at runtime, how do I achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it with a simple conversion like this:

```
    public class Chmod {

        public Set<PosixFilePermission> fromInt(int perms) {
            final char[] ds = Integer.toString(perms).toCharArray();
            final char[] ss = {'-','-','-','-','-','-','-','-','-'};
            for (int i = ds.length-1; i >= 0; i--) {
                int n = ds[i] - '0';
                if (i == ds.length-1) {
                    if ((n & 1) != 0) ss[8] = 'x';
                    if ((n & 2) != 0) ss[7] = 'w';
                    if ((n & 4) != 0) ss[6] = 'r';
                }
                else if (i == ds.length-2) {
                    if ((n & 1) != 0) ss[5] = 'x';
                    if ((n & 2) != 0) ss[4] = 'w';
                    if ((n & 4) != 0) ss[3] = 'r';
                }
                else if (i == ds.length-3) {
                    if ((n & 1) != 0) ss[2] = 'x';
                    if ((n & 2) != 0) ss[1] = 'w';
                    if ((n & 4) != 0) ss[0] = 'r';
                }
            }
            String sperms = new String(ss);
            System.out.printf("%d -> %s\n", perms, sperms);
            return PosixFilePermissions.fromString(sperms);
        }

        public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
            Chmod test = new Chmod();
            test.fromInt(444);
            test.fromInt(1);
            test.fromInt(777);
            test.fromInt(666);
            test.fromInt(604);
            test.fromInt(0);
        }

    }
```

Comment: Thanks a ton for this, I have hit a use case when I am getting mode in file:stat:mode format which are 5 digit numbers like 16895, how do I handle these?

Comment: @SamayraGoyal, you can extend the code with the additional bits. See: https://superuser.com/a/669638/753829

Answer (score 2):

You simply figure how these numbers come into existence, quoting [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File_system_permissions):

### Numeric notation

Another method for representing Unix permissions is an octal (base-8) notation as shown by stat -c %a. This notation consists of at least three digits. Each of the three rightmost digits represents a different component of the permissions: owner, group, and others. (If a fourth digit is present, the leftmost (high-order) digit addresses three additional attributes, the setuid bit, the setgid bit and the sticky bit.)

Each of these digits is the sum of its component bits in the binary numeral system. As a result, specific bits add to the sum as it is represented by a numeral:

- The read bit adds 4 to its total (in binary 100),
- The write bit adds 2 to its total (in binary 010), and
- The execute bit adds 1 to its total (in binary 001).

... end quote

In other words: you need to do a bit of binary masking to figure the r,w,x chars required to express that number.

You can do that manually, see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34234598/how-to-convert-an-input-of-3-octal-numbers-into-chmod-permissions-into-binary) or [there](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36618977/linux-file-permissionsin-depth-numeric-to-string-notation-and-vice-versa-a).

Comment: You may also need to do some special handling of group sticky bit and suid bit (i.e. u+s and g+s)

Comment: Is there any Api which does this directly?

Comment: Why? What I meant is Is there a way that instead of PosixFilePermissions.fromString("-rw-r--r--") i can do PosixFilePermissions.fromInt(450);

Comment: Java would be pretty weird if it is unable to set file permissions using the numeric notation.

Comment: Thats what I was wondering, there should be something available instead of me doing all the parsing.

Comment: There are lots of things that are strangely absent in java

Comment: Its very sad :(